# preserve node in xslt transformation

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

```
<root>
<tag>
  <form>
   some html form will be here
  </form>

</tag>
<tag>
  some visible data
</tag>
```

**xslt**

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <div id="page-base">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

**produce**

```
<div id="page-base">

</div>
<div id="page-base">
 some visible data
</div>
```

**Desired output**

```
<div id="page-base">
 <form>
   some html form will be here
  </form>
</div>
<div id="page-base">
 some visible data
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

What if `tag` is nested in `tag` element where the templates rules applies it will replace the tag with the templates and will copy other element where templates does not match. please see the example. `tag` could be aribtrary nested

```
<root>
        <tag>
          <form>
           some html form will be here
          </form>
          <tag>
            arbitrary nested tags
          </tag>    
        </tag>
        <tag>
          some visible data
        </tag>
</root>
```

**expected result**

```
 <div id="page-base">
     <form>
       some html form will be here
      </form>
      <div id="page-base">
       arbitrary nested tags  
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="page-base">
     some visible data
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="tag">
  <div id="page-base">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <tag>
        <form>
   some html form will be here
        </form>
    </tag>
    <tag>
  some visible data
    </tag>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<div id="page-base">
   <form>
   some html form will be here
        </form>
</div>
<div id="page-base">
  some visible data
    </div>
```

**Explanation**:

Your code lacked something to copy the body of the matched `tag` element.

This "something" is the **[`xsl:copy-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#copy-of)** instruction.

---

**Update**:

The OP has changed his question and this requires a different solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tag">
  <div id="page-base">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the newly-provided XML document:**

```
<div id="page-base">
   <form>
           some html form will be here
          </form>
   <div id="page-base">
            arbitrary nested tags
          </div>
</div>
<div id="page-base">
          some visible data
        </div>
```

Comment: if i use `copy-of` will it use templates match which is inside that node?

Comment: @user1538127, `xsl:copy-of` does what it names says -- it copies to the output all nodes that are selected by the expression specified in its `select` attribute. You may follow the link in my answer and read more about this instruction.

Comment: @user1538127, You don't provide the wanted result for the new case. Please, edit the question and do so.

Comment: @ dimitre Done, please see it now.

Comment: @user1538127, Yes, I added an update (at the very end) to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [copy rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will simply copy any node not matching a more descriptive template. Due to the catchall nature of the matching rule, other rules will take precedence unless you tweak their priorities, in which case you should assign this rule a [priority](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict) lower than any other.

if you only want to copy some part of the tree, you should add a separate mode for it, which you'll have to specify whenever you call apply that template.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tag">
  <div id="page-base">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you may also do a deep copy using [`copy-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#copy-of). But the above approach still is more flexible, as it allows you to omit or transform certain nodes from the copy.